# How do I launch an app at boot/startup on Sierra?

Tags: startup, launchd, macos

I'm a techie but fairly new to macOS. I am using a Mac mini running macOS Sierra as a build machine running [GoCD](https://www.go.cd/). I want the server (go-server) and the agent (go-agent) to start on boot, but I can't find an easy explanation anywhere for how to do this.

Things that worked on Mac OS X 10.6 don't work any more, and I **don't** want to have these apps start at *login*, because I don't want to remain logged into the console on this computer.

Comment: Have you looked at launch services/daemons?

Comment: @dante12 Please read the question: DrS explicitly doesn't want to start the app/service at login but at boot time.

Answer (score 5):

Service/app launch while booting is usually done with launchd and launch daemons controlled by launchctl. It depends on the app/executable and the environment if such a launch daemon is possible or not. A lot of GUI apps require a login session and the method doesn't work.

After inspecting GoCD you can either download a [zip file](https://download.go.cd/binaries/16.10.0-4131/generic/go-server-16.10.0-4131.zip) or an ["OS X/macOS app" version](https://download.go.cd/binaries/16.10.0-4131/osx/go-server-16.10.0-4131-osx.zip) of the server. The server is started with a shell script in both cases: either explicitly in the zip version or implicitly with "Go Server.app/Contents/MacOS/go-server".

Go with the zip file, unzip it and move the resulting folder to /usr/local. Link the folder /usr/local/go-server-16.10.0 to /usr/local/:

```
ln -s /usr/local/go-server-16.10.0 /usr/local/go-server
```

Create a launch daemon with `sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemon/org.goserver.start.plist`and the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.goserver.start</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/usr/local/go-server/server.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/org.goserver.start.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/org.goserver.start.stdout</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Change owner and permissions of the file if necessary:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.goserver.start.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.goserver.start.plist
```

Modify /usr/local/go-server-16.10.0/server.sh to your needs. You should set a different log directory in line 85 or a log file will be created in the root directory. Check other variables and paths (like $JAVA_HOME, YOURKIT_PATH, $PID_FILE etc) in the shell script and modify them according to your needs/environment. Here it worked out-of-the-box - but I didn't test it thoroughly.

Then start the launch daemon with:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.goserver.start.plist
```

Check /tmp/org.goserver.start.stderr for launchd errors. If the launch daemon runs well you may remove the part:

```
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/org.goserver.start.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/org.goserver.start.stdout</string>
```

from the plist.

The method should work accordingly with the GoAgent. The start of the agent is done with agent.sh. Use a second plist with a different plist and label name of course: org.goagent.start.plist/org.goagent.start.

You probably have to add a condition in the agent's plist so that the agent is started after the server is running.

---

I tried the same with the "OS X" app but I failed to eliminate all errors.